# Camel Context cvc 2.4.2 error which doesnt find the camelContext

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I know and had been through a lot of similar problems like this. But still i am not getting where i am missing out. I have specified the latest xsds in name space. Still i get the error when i run in Web Sphere. But i dont get any problems with Tomcat.

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
   http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
">



<bean id="xRoute" class="com.tgt.test.web.routes.GetXRoute" />
<bean id="yRoute" class="com.tgt.test.web.routes.YRoute" />
<bean id="zRoute" class="com.tgt.test.web.routes.ZRoute" />
    <camelContext id="camelContext" trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
   <routeBuilder ref="xRoute"/>
    <routeBuilder ref="yRoute"/>
    <routeBuilder ref="zRoute"/>
</camelContext>
```

ERROR: Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camelContext'.

please let me know why this happens only with wbesphere but not with Tomcat. And Sorry for asking for same question.I have been breaking my head since yesterday.Thanks

Comment: Please can someone help me out with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was working in Web sphere RSA Environment. It was working fine in a NON EAR type of Project Structure with TOMCAT Container. But when i moved my code to EAR type of Project Structure, It occured that

**ERROR:** Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camelContext'.

Which means , the Spring coudnt find a declaration for the Element çamelContext'which is supposed to be there in "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" which had a namespace reference -> "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd" So i check the camel-spring.xsd file in camel sprin 2.12.1 jar, the camelContext was there. Then i recognized that the the camel-spring jar  was not recognized by the EAR,even though i have added them to classpath (adding to class path means, (properties/build path/add jars) for each project. So the solution is,

got to EAR/META_INF and add all the jars which are required in the class path for each project.

This solution solved the issue.Though this wasted almost 48 hours of my precious development time, it was worth the wait. I learnt more. Thanks!