# Unable to start camel spring context in jboss environment

Tags: spring, jboss, apache-camel

I have created a camel spring file as below. The file uses a routebuilder class already present in the code. Its not able to parse the xml and hence the applicationcontext is unable to start properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:camel="http://www.camel.apache.org/schema/spring"  
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            spring-beans.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            spring-tx.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            spring-context.xsd  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.19.1.xsd">

    <bean id="ValidateAndUpdateBatchRoute" class="com.camelkafka.ValidateAndUpdateBatchRoute" />
    <camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <camel:routeBuilder ref="ValidateAndUpdateBatchRoute" />
    </camel:camelContext>

</beans>
```

But when start jboss it throws the following exception.

```
16:09:20,181 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/RDAWorkFlowEjb-17.6]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 125) JBWEB000289: Servlet startup threw load() exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 68; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camel:camelContext'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:196)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:390)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:322)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:281)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:446)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3271)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1993)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:724)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1653)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:845)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:768)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252) [spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127) [spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93) [spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) [spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612) [spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513) [spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) [spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) [spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.alu.oss.mdf.rda.workflow.util.WorkFlowUtil.initialize(WorkFlowUtil.java:73) [classes:]
    at com.alu.oss.mdf.rda.workflow.servlets.StartUpServlet.init(StartUpServlet.java:18) [classes:]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3593) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3802) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
```

Unable to understand what is missing from the spring xml file. I have added the dependency in the module.xml of jboss for third party dependency as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camelContext spring xml file should look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans spring-beans.xsd 
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring camel-spring.xsd">

    <bean id="jbossResolver" class="org.apacheextras.camel.jboss.JBossPackageScanClassResolver"/>
    <bean id="ValidateAndUpdateBatchRoute" class="com.camelkafka.ValidateAndUpdateBatchRoute" />
    <camel:camelContext>
        <camel:routeBuilder ref="ValidateAndUpdateBatchRoute" />
    </camel:camelContext>
 </beans>
```

The dependency for camel-core and camel-spring should be as follows:

Camel-core- located at org/apache/camel/core:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.apache.camel.core">
        <resources>
                <resource-root path="camel-core-2.19.1.jar"/>
                <resource-root path="jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar"/>
                <resource-root path="jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar"/>
                <resource-root path="camel-jboss6-2.18.0.jar"/>
                <resource-root path="camel-spring-2.19.1.jar"/>
        </resources>
        <dependencies>
                <module name="org.springframework"/>
                <module name="org.slf4j"/>
                <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
                <module name="javax.api"/>
                <module name="sun.jdk" />
                <module name="org.jboss.vfs" />
        </dependencies>
</module>
```

Next camel-spring- located at org/apache/camel/spring:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.apache.camel.spring">
        <resources>
                <resource-root path="camel-spring-2.19.1.jar"/>
                <resource-root path="camel-jboss6-2.18.0.jar"/>
        </resources>
        <dependencies>
                <module name="org.springframework"/>
                <module name="org.slf4j"/>
                <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
                <module name="javax.api"/>
                <module name="org.apache.camel.core" />
                <module name="org.jboss.vfs" />
        </dependencies>
</module>
```

Also make sure to add camel-spring.xsd into classpath as well. This should be started as shown below:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camelContext.xml");
```

This is worked fine for me. Hope it helps others as well for using camel in jboss EAP.

For some reason the camel thirdparty jars configured in jboss was not picked up. I had to put the jars in WEB-INF/lib for it to work.

Answer (score -1):

Change the location of `http://www.camel.apache.org/schema/spring` namespace to use `http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.19.1.xsd`! (without the www.)

Comment: That solved the warning of namespace. But the Servlet startup threw load() exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 68; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camel:camelContext'. still exists.

Comment: Check this thread for the other error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354161/camel-context-cvc-2-4-2-error-which-doesnt-find-the-camelcontext